# How to use map properly?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this method:

```
getAnnouncements() {
    this.restService.get('announcement').subscribe(data => {
        this.announcements = data['payload'];
        this.optionsFromDb = this.announcements;
        this.options = this.optionsFromDb.map(option => ({checked: false, code: option.code, name: option.name}));
    });
}
```

In html I have this:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let option of options">
    <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="option.checked" (change)="option.checked = !option.checked" />
        <span>{{option.name}}</span>
    </label>
</div>

getListOfChecked() {
    return this.options.map( announcement => announcement.checked );
}
```

What I want is to display this option.name in html, but remove it from options. Any suggestion how can I do that? Because my post function receives only checked and code, not a name, thats why i want to remove it

Comment: I didn't understand, you want to display the name and remove from object?

Comment: yes.. i want to remove it from object because function for post recives only checked and code, and not name...so when i send options to send only those two parameters

Comment: if i remove name:option.name in .ts from options then i dont see it on html

Comment: Why do you need to remove the name but still display it? The problem is that you're binding to the name. You have to keep it somewhere to be able to use binding. Maybe you want to store a copy with the name and a copy without the name for some reason?

Comment: @rmc00 i need name for checkbox so that user can see the name of checkbox what he choose every of that checkbox have code and checked (true,false) ... so i only need those two to pass to other function, but right now it take and name that i dont need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you want to display the name, but remove it before you send it to your web service, right ?

If you want to use map to do that, just do

```
let paylaodToSendToBackend = this.options.map(option => ({ checked: option.checked, code: option.code }));
```

before your HTTP call.